# Название знака Учёный муж не толерантно

Tags: предложение, знаки

Название знака [Учёный муж](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/56/pundit) может быть воспринято как дискриминация, так как слово "муж" подразумевает мужской пол. Возможно, следует его поменять?

Comment: Заголовок не понял. Что значит "не толерантно"? И разве "дискриминация" не про ущемление чьих-то прав, этот знак не выдают женщинам что-ли?

Comment: Мне кажется, что это фразеологизм. А любой фразеологизм по значению равен отдельному слову или словосочетанию (в данном случае, к примеру, `учёный человек`). Поэтому нельзя рассматривать составляющие его слова и пытаться делать вывод о их толерантности.

Comment: А также поменять/удалить/запретить в русском языке все слова, в которых есть корень "муж". Так его!

Comment: И холостым этот знак не выдавать...

Comment: .. и людям без ученой степени, подтвержденной справкой из ЖЭКа тоже

Comment: Уже оставлял комментарий, перефразирую: а какие варианты для замены?

Comment: @РустамГимранов У меня нет определенного варианта замены. Если бы был - написал сразу.

Comment: Тогда может оставить как есть и не проявлять преждевременную заботу об участниках (которых задевает данное словосочетание), пока они не появятся? Если появятся, то пусть предлагают варианты.

Answer (score 2):

слово "*учёный"* также весьма не толерантно, по отношению к *"двоешникам"* коим являюсь я.

Посему предлагаю заменить слово  *"учёный"*  на *"дышащий"* (так как все мы от рождения умеем дышать и это не кого не дискриминирует ).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А слово *"муж"* на слово  *"амёба"* (так как амёбы размножаются без полым путём **"нет полов нет проблемы :3 "**)

так что пора дискриминирующего патриархального выражения  [Учёный муж](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/56/pundit)  пора переходить на правильное не дискриминационное  [Дышащая амёба](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/56/pundit)

Comment: Вы забыли толерантный род. Учёный/-ая/-ое